# In tensorflow, how to evaluate a Neuron Net without actually training it

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, data-science

In tensorflow, I want to evaluate the model after each epoch with the same test data set. What I did:

```
    # Train data.
    cTr,train_summary,_ = sess.run([loss,summary_op,optimizer], feed_dict={input_tensor: batch_xTr,output_tensor:batch_yTr})
    # Test data.
    batch_xTe,batch_yTe = get_batch(newsgroups_test,0,len(newsgroups_test.target)) # can also be adjusted batch size
    cTe,test_summary, _ = sess.run([loss,summary_op, optimizer], feed_dict={input_tensor: batch_xTe,output_tensor:batch_yTe})
```

The result is that the model can reach nearly 100% accuracy at last. It's not reasonable and the reason might be that I'm actually "training" while evaluating.

Is there anyway that I can evaluate the model without actually "training" it with the test data?

Comment: Yes, there are some ways.

Comment: Read this (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) with focus under **Get answers to practical, detailed questions**, then update your question.

Comment: I have read the tour and updated my question. Thanks for the instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run the optimizer with the test data. Try this

```
cTe = sess.run([loss], feed_dict={input_tensor: batch_xTe, output_tensor: batch_yTe})
```

Comment: That works! I was not that familiar with the sess.run() api, which resulted in my confusion.